# Minifyenabled produces error

Tags: android

When I try to export my signed app, I get this error message:

> Warning:Exception while processing task java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   C:\Users\Username\AndroidStudioProjects\Project\app\build\intermediates\proguard-rules\release\aapt_rules.txt

What should I do?

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28168161/filenotfoundexception-on-proguard-rules-pro-file)

Comment: @StephenLightcap nope this file exists.

Comment: hmm, did you try to clean and rebuild the project? [Here is a thread with some solutions that might help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42726326/aapt-rules-txt-not-found-when-building-apk-in-android-studio)

Comment: wonderful, that worked!